# C++ Builder > TControl.Parent property > does the parent free the children?

Tags: c++builder

My environment:

```
C++ Builder 10.2 Tokyo on Windows 10 v1809
```

I have a question about TControl.Parent property.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    TPanel *pnlptr = new TPanel(/*AOwner=*/this);
    TLabel *lblptr = new TLabel(/*AOwner=*/this);
    lblptr->Parent = pnlptr;

    // some processing

    //delete lblptr;
    delete pnlptr;
}
```

Does the above code free the lblptr?

In the document (for 2009 although)
[TControl.Parent Property](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Controls_TControl_Parent.html)

> Note: The Parent property declared in TControl is similar to the Owner property declared in TComponent, in that the Parent of a control frees the control just as the Owner of a component frees that Component.

With the note, I think when the pnlptr is freed, the lblptr is also freed without `delete lblptr`.

Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the above code free the lblptr?

Yes, it does.  When the `TPanel` is freed, its base `TWinControl` destructor frees any components that are still in the `Controls[]` property (controls that have the `TWinControl` set as their `Parent`):

```
destructor TWinControl.Destroy;
var
  I: Integer;
  Instance: TControl;
begin
  ...
  I := ControlCount;
  while I <> 0 do
  begin
    Instance := Controls[I - 1];
    Remove(Instance);
    Instance.Destroy; // <-- FREED HERE
    I := ControlCount;
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for your information. With your reply, I found that I can check it by reading the source code of the TWinControl.Destroy. It will help me to understand more on the other things.